# Storing different data types in single column using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have three different type of geospatial data `Road Direction`, `Pinpoint location with/without radius`, `Custom define area` which I want to store. If I understood it right this would need three different data types for postgis column, `LINESTRING`, `POINT`, `POLYGON` respectively.

Now the problem for me is these three different types represents a single entity which you can say `place_user_interested_in`

Can I store these three different types in single column?

The reason why should I store this in single column is to make it more flexible to add more data types later if needed and it would be easier to perform same actions on all of these in single query and some other relevant stuff

Comment: Just create the geometry column as general "geometry" and you can store all kind of geometries into it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment and in one of my questions (and the answers therein) - [What's the benefit of heterogeneous geometry column in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176381), you can store different types of geometry in the same field, if you don't specify specific geometry type. i.e. if you create your table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl AS (..., geom geometry);
```

, instead of giving the field a specific type

```
CREATE TABLE tbl AS (..., geom geometry(linestring));
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE tbl AS (..., geom geometry(multilinestring));
```

etc.

In the first approach, you can store mixed geometries. In the second approach, you can only store the specified type of geometries as with ArcGIS and other systems.

Answer (score 4):

> I have three different type of geospatial data Road Direction, Pinpoint location with/without radius, Custom define area which I want to store.[...] The reason why should I store this in single column is to make it more flexible to add more data types later if needed and it would be easier to perform same actions on all of these in single query and some other relevant stuff

That doesn't make it more flexible. There is work to be done. You can do the work now, and maintain a tight schema which means querying it is fast and easy for the end-user and the database,

[image: clean drawer]

Or you can relax now, load up your stuff in to a heaping drunk drawer and delay the work until later, and deal with it every time you need something.

[image: drunk drawer]

The above is heterogeneous geometry column. It's certainly more flexible and less taxing on mental health and time to **just do it right** before you get to that point. Just put things where they belong, you won't regret it.